# Scala peephole optimization for JVMNodes

Tags: scala

I'm not sure how to modify a recursive method call to handle a list of JVMNodes, which I would pass in to be checked and replaced with different JVM commands to peephole optimize the language. Each case will be a different JVM command stored in the list, which is then replaced for optimizaiton if needed, and then passed to the new optimized list.

```
def processSequence(oldlist:List[JVMNode], newlist:List[JVMNode]):List[JVMNode] = {

  def listMatch(list: List[Int], newlist:List[JVMNode]): Int = {
    list match {
      case Nil => currentSum
      case x :: xs => listMatch(list[x], newlist[xs])
    }
  }
    listMatch(list, 0)
}
```

Comment: your code is not clear. what is `currentSum` and what is `list`?
and it's not clear what is the relation between the question and the code.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of what you are trying to achieve, it looks like you should be able to do what you want with the standard `List` methods.

If you want to replace one `JVMNode` with another node, use `map` and pass a function that converts the old node to the new now optimised node (or return the original if there is no optimisation)

If a single `JVMNode` in the original list might produce a different number of optimisied nodes, use `flatMap` and pass a function that converts the old node into a list of new nodes.

If you want to extract a single value by processing each `JVMNode` in turn, use `foldLeft` and pass an initial value and a function that updates that value based on the contents of a node.

If you do need to use a recursive function to process a `List`, it might look something like this:

```
def myMap[T](list: List[T], f: T => T): List[T] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(list: List[T], newList: List[T]): List[T] = {
    list match {
      case Nil => newList.reverse
      case x :: xs =>
        val newX = f(x)

        loop(xs, newX +: newList)
    }
  }

  loop(list, Nil)
}
```

This does the same as `map` but should give an idea of how to structure a recursive function on a `List`. The code in the `loop` function can see all the nodes in the `List`, in case it needs to look at the context of a node. It can also choose how many nodes to add to the result, and even modify the previous nodes if necessary.

Two things to note here:

- The result is passed down as a parameter to `loop` so that `loop` is a tail-recursive function and can be optimised.
- The result is built in reverse order and then reversed at the end because adding to the front of a `List` is much faster than adding to the end of a `List`.